# Laravel 4 Error

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm a newbie in Laravel and i'm trying to make login page but there's an error that i didn't understand

```
 [2017-03-04 08:14:52] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:148
    Stack trace:
    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1049): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1017): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(746): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
    #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
    #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
    #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
    #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(642): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
    #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\ecinema\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
    #11 {main} [] []
```

Here's my controller

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('login');
}

public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}

public function login()
{

    if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('username'), 'password' => Input::get('password')),true))
    {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('login')->withInput()->with('flash_error', 'Wrong Username or Password');

    }
}
```

and here's my routes

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('login');

// route to process the form
Route::get('login',function()
{
return View::make('login');
});

//login route post
Route::post('login','HomeController@login');
```

Here's my view -> login.blade.php

```
                                        {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}

                                            {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('id'=>'username', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Username *')) }}
                                              </br>
                                            {{ Form::password('password',array('id'=>'password', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Password *')) }}
                                               </br>
                                               <span>
                                            {{ Form::submit('Login>>',array('class'=>'button')) }} 
                                    {{ Form::close() }}

                                             <div class="text-center">
                                             {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                                            @if ($errors->any())
                                            <ul>
                                                {{ implode('', $errors->all('<li class="error">:message</p>')) }}
                                            </ul>
                                            @endif
```

Can anyone please check to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting the error when you visit a url or when you post a form? Also, what is the url when you get the error?

Comment: @RossWilson this is the url: 'url' => 'login'

Comment: @RossWilson the error occur when i post the login

Comment: In that case can you show your form?

Comment: @RossWilson sure, i added the view code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me it turns out I use two Form::open and Form::close. After I delete one of them it runs perfectly fine